# Access originalFile Name for file parameter

Tags: hudson

In my hudson project I want to use the file parameter and process the uploaded fiel in an ANT Job.
Therefore I need to know the location and the originalFileName.
How can I access these two values?

Answer (score 0):

You have the current location and file name. You can't know where the original file is, it can be on a completely different computer.

But since you have a copy of your file (see the file location of the file parameter), you can pass that file into your ant job.